# Extend a component with same selector - Angular 2 / Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, inheritance, webpack, angular-cli, aot

We're using angular to build a nice component front end for our core application. We have multiple clients who request very minor customisation of those core components. I want to preserve our core code in NPM packages and then make those slight modifications by extending components in each client app.

In order to do this I need to extend a child component, but keep the same selector (otherwise I have to modify each parent component).

I've been able to do this with aot=false builds by importing the original component into the extending component and using a relative link to the node_modules for the templateUrl. Then I declare the extending component in the app.module and drop the original component from the app.module (so the selectors don't conflict).

This works fine as long as aot=false, but with aot true, I get a "ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class " error for the original component on build.

Is there any way to extend one component from another, keep the selector the same, and still benefit from AOT compilation?

Comment: You could use base classes without `@Component()` annotations and only add those to the concrete implementarions.

Comment: Can you please share the decision that you took?  Did you take Mau's advice?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I think we probably never got past leaving aot=false because I left the project shortly after this question was posted. I think @Mau is right that my approach needed to be reconsidered. I'd probably look into mixins if I were approaching this again. This is a helpful article https://medium.com/@jordan.eckowitz/javascript-composition-vs-inheritance-4b99234593a9 Wish I had a better response for you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can achieve your goal without changing strategy (take a look at [selector-conflicts](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#selector-conflicts)).

Personally, I would try to use the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) mechanism combined with a customer class ([Injection Beyond Classes](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/angular2/injection_beyond_classes.html)) that gives you the right implementation of your component: if you have a customer one, you load that; otherwise the default one.

Of course, components will have different selectors.